# Creating multiple column legend

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns, legend

I use MATLAB to draw a graph. The legends are too big and cover a part of the graph. I want to split the entries of the legend in two columns. I saw some solutions on the net that explain how to change the functions to display the legend in multiple columns. However, my program reads the data from an Excel file and their solutions don't work for me. Could anybody please help me to solve this issue? Sorry if my question is naive, I'm not good in MATLAB.

Here is my code:

```
A=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','A1:A10');
B=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','B1:B10');
C=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','C1:C10');
D=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','D1:D10');
E=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','E1:E10');
F=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','F1:F10');
G=xlsread('C:\temp.xlsx','G1:G10');
plot(A,B,A,C,A,D,A,E,A,F,A,G)
hold on;
axis([10 100 -10 0])
xlabel('length')
ylabel('BER')
legend('AAAAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBBB','CCCCCCCCCC','DDDDDDDDDD','EEEEEEEEEEE','FFFFFFFFFF')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different links to matlab-files that should solve your problem:

- [ColumnLegend](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-columnlegend)
- [GridLegend](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29248-gridlegend-a-multi-column-format-for-legends)

The creation of the legend should be independent on how you read your data, so the fact that you read your data from Excel should not give you any problems!